# "Merged hierarchies can be used in reports (New)" New Feature in BO 4.1

Tags: business-objects

Firstly, I would like to say that I am dissapointed when it comes to documentation for SAP BusinessObjects (At present we are using vesion 4.1). I can't believe that such system has such unuseful if any documentation/tutorials that cover real life examples. This is really discouraging.

Now I am comming to my question: In version 4.1. it is stated that the new version offers following feature: "Merged hierarchies can be used in reports (New)". The question is - is it possible to implement collapse/expand functionality in 4.1 version in the same way as it is displayed in the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEAhfX2Bqc8 (starting from 2:08 minutes). If yes - could anyone please explain how to implement the functionality or send a video tutorial that tacles with this issue?
(I assumed that the mentioned new feature is the same as the feature shown in the video, which is implemented with BEX queries. We are not using BEX queries, but our data basis is database that resides on SQL server.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hierarchies are specific to OLAP environments (e.g. SQL Server Analysis Services or SAP BW through BICS). If you're using a relational database such as SQL Server, there is no such thing as a hierarchy.

Do not confuse this with *navigation paths* (Information Design Tool - IDT) or *object hierarchies* (Universe Design Tool – UDT).

From the documentation:

> A navigation path is an object that defines the drill path used in SAP
>   BusinessObjects reporting tools. A drill path is a list of drillable
>   business objects that allow a report analyst to drill down on a
>   dimension.

Thus, a navigation path or object hierarchy is only used to define drill paths in your document, not to hierarchically define your data in a given dimension.

More information about this:

- Navigation paths: [Information Design Tool User Guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41sp3_info_design_tool_en.pdf), paragraph 12.14: *About navigation paths for objects*
- Object hierarchies: [Universe Designer](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir31SP3/en/xi31_sp3_designer_en.pdf), page 364: *Defining hierarchies*

If you're looking for documentation on SAP BusinessObjects, try these resources:

- [Analytics Knowledge Center](http://help.sap.com/boall_en/)
- [Official Product Tutorials – SAP BI Suite](http://www.sap.com/LearnBI)